# Pandas groupby top5 products

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to 'recieve top5 product from categories'.

[image]

```
import panda as pd
gg=pd.read_excel(product.xlsx)
gg.groupby(['Category','Product'])['Sale'].sum().sort_values(by='sum', ascending=False).head(5)
```

Comment: But this code got top5 category/product from all table. What groupby i should use???

Comment: Instead of posting data as an image/screenshot post data as text so that we can reproduce your dataframe

Comment: We can not copy the data from image, it's recommended to add your data as text.

Answer (score 0):

Example data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Category': np.random.choice(['TV', 'Phone', 'Computer'], size=n),
                        'Product': np.random.randint(low=100, high=1000, size=n),
                        'Sales': np.random.randint(low=10, high=10000, size=n)})
```

Then, we can use the `nlargest` series method to get what you are looking for:

`df.set_index(['Category','Product']).Sales.groupby('Category',group_keys=False).nlargest(3)`

```
Category  Product
Computer  565        9997
          992        9739
          773        9060
Phone     242        9720
          300        9380
          744        9297
TV        891        9271
          552        9264
          752        9030
Name: Sales, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I see I did top 3 instead of top 5 - just change the 3 to 5. Did this work for you?

Comment: @Alexosipov feel free to accept the answer to close.